# UIGestureRecognizer - Get the reference to the touched UIViewController Instead of its View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

How do I get a reference to the UIViewController of a touched view?

I am using a UIPanGestureRecognizer on the view of a UIViewController. Here's how I initialize it:

```
    TaskUIViewController *thisTaskController = [[TaskUIViewController alloc]init];
    [[self view]addSubview:[thisTaskController view]];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [[thisTaskController view] addGestureRecognizer:panRec];
```

In the tiggered action triggered using the gesture recognizer I am able to get the view from the parameter using **recognizer.view**

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UIView *touchedView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    touchedView = (UIView*)[recognizer view];
    ...
}
```

However what I really need is the underlying UIViewController of the view touched. How can I get a reference to the UIViewController that contains this view instead of only the UIView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it is more a design issue than just getting a reference. So I would follow several simple advises:

1. Owner should catch events from its view. I.e. TaskUIViewController sould be a target to UIPanGestureRecognizer which you added to its view.
2. If a controller has a sub-controller and waits from its sub-controller some responses - implement this as delegate.
3. You have memory leak in your "handlePan:" method.

Here is a skeleton to solve your issue:

```
@protocol CallbackFromMySubcontroller <NSObject>
- (void)calbackFromTaskUIViewControllerOnPanGesture:(UIViewController*)fromController;
@end

@interface OwnerController : UIViewController <CallbackFromMySubcontroller>
@end

@implementation OwnerController

- (id)init
{
    ...
    TaskUIViewController *thisTaskController = [[TaskUIViewController alloc] init];
    ...
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
   [self.view addSubview:thisTaskController.view];
    ...
}

- (void)calbackFromTaskUIViewControllerOnPanGesture:(UIViewController*)fromController
{
    NSLog(@"Yahoo. I got an event from my subController's view");
}

@end


@interface TaskUIViewController : UIViewController {
    id <CallbackFromMySubcontroller> delegate;
}
@end

@implementation TaskUIViewController

- (id)initWithOwner:(id<CallbackFromMySubcontroller>)owner
{
    ...
    delegate = owner;
    ...
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRec];
    [panRec release];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    ...
    [delegate calbackFromTaskUIViewControllerOnPanGesture:self];
    ...
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What you write makes much sense to me. However with the GesturerRecognizer inside the UIViewController, the program now crashes as soon as I trigger the pan event with a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS..." error. Unfortunately not more hints on the cause are provided. Any idea on this?

Comment: Just check if you set correct target inside gesture as well as correct handler. There is no magic, just a code :)

Comment: I did it as you proposed "UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];" all within the UIViewController's viewDidLoad method. The "handlePan" method exists as well... puzzling

Comment: Try to replace IBAction with void inside handlePan: method name. I fixed the code. Check also if you have no links from some XIB to this handlePan:. I corrected the code example.

Comment: Sorry, still getting the "EXC_BAD_ACCESS..." error. I am trying to ask another question giving more details on my implementation. But I think your approach shows the right way. So again, thanks for that.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: I think you have to submit another question, man. I answered to exact question with my suggestion.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: So you down-voting the answer because in new circumstances you just brought up it looks incomplete?

Comment: @SVGreg you haven't simply answered the question. You add gesture recognizer inside view controller you need and this controller contains a gesture handler method. So you just write `self` which is a pointer to your controller and so you can call any method inside it. Other code you wrote is extra. And of course the question doesn't say that this code is inside another view controller. So your case occurs frequently but it is particular

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: I'm not sure you've got a point. My code is not exact implementation but rather a sketch which describes the idea. If you have better one - just submit it. I do not see any answer from you.

Comment: @SVGreg Ok. You store a link to view a link to its owner controller - property, "associated object" and etc. It is normal because the owner controller's lifetime is longer than its view

Answer (score 0):

`[touchedView nextResponder]` will return the `UIViewController` object that manages `touchedView` (if it has one) or `touchedView`'s superview (if it doesn’t have a `UIViewController` object that manages it).

For more information, see the [UIResponder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  (`UIViewController` and `UIView` are subclasses of `UIResponder`.)

In your case, since you happen to know that `touchedView` is your viewController's view (and not, for instance, a subview of your viewController's view), you can just use:

```
TaskUIViewController *touchedController = (TaskUIViewController *)[touchedView nextResponder];
```

In the more general case, you could work up the responder chain until you find an object of kind UIViewController:

```
id aNextResponder = [touchedView nextResponder];

while (aNextResponder != nil)
{
  if ([aNextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
  {
    // we have found the viewController that manages touchedView,
    // so we break out of the while loop:
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    // we have yet to find the managing viewController,
    // so we examine the next responder in the responder chain
    aNextResponder = [aNextResponder nextResponder];
  }
}

// outside the while loop.  at this point aNextResponder points to
// touchedView's managing viewController (or nil if it doesn't have one).
UIViewController *eureka = (UIViewController *)aNextResponder;
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like the right direction. I tried to use it like this: 
TaskUIViewController *touchedController = [[TaskUIViewController alloc]init];
    touchedController = (TaskUIViewController*)[touchedView nextResponder];
    NSLog(@"Recognizer: %@",touchedController);
I still get a pointer to a UIView back not a UIViewController. Did I address it correctly?

Comment: @BerndPlontsch  You don't need to alloc/init a new `TaskUIViewController`.  Just use `TaskUIViewController *touchedController = (TaskUIViewController *)[touchedView nextResponder];`  (See the sample code that I have added in my expanded answer above.)